# Pivot Wider in R with NRC dict "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level"

Tags: r, tidyr

I am new to R and currently using it for data mining on yelp reviews.

I am currently trying to `pivot_wider` on the NRC dictionary but keep getting the following error:

```
"Values in `idf` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(idf = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(idf = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(idf = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
no loop for break/next, jumping to top level"
```

this is the code I am trying to run to `pivot_wider`:

```
revDTM_sentiNRC <- rrSenti_nrc %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(review_id,stars), 
              names_from = word, 
              values_from = idf) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I have done the same with the AFINN and Bing dictionaries with success.

I have tried adding R's suggestions from the error in the code but this does not work. I have also tried using this code for the duplicates

```
rrSenti_nrc <- group_by(review_id) %>% distinct(words, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

this however gives me the following error:

```
"Error in group_by(review_id) : object 'review_id' not found"
```

Which I do not understand because the rest of my code is able to find 'review_id' but perhaps this is the wrong approach to tackling the issue.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/help.

Comment: Can you share the data using `dput` ?

Comment: Your `group_by` command is failing because you’re missing the first argument... the data frame you want to group.

Comment: I think the issue here is that words are in the AFINN and Bing lexicons **one** time each but they are in the NRC lexicon **multiple** times. Can you share a small reproducible example so we can see how to solve this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example